# Link -static GTK+-2.0 program in MSYS2 (with mingw64, NOT mingw32) for Windows 10

Tags: c, windows, gcc, gtk2, msys2

I have a program which compiles perfectly in Linux, and compiles in Windows if I don't try to link it with `-static` flag. (I have to say I didn't try `-static` in linux, as I don't find it useful).

Also, although it links non-statically in windows without errors, it later fails finding the `.dll`s when I run the program.

Using: `MSYS2` (x64) with `mingw64` in `Windows 10` (x64) (everything is 64bit).

When I try to link it statically, it gives the following error in the last stage:

```
 MINGW64 ~/mine-sweeper
$ make OS=win    
        CC      about_mod.o
        CC      ctrl_mod.o
        CC      game_mod.o
        CC      menu_mod.o
        CC      player_mod.o
        CC      save_mod.o
        CC      xyzzy_mod.o
        LD      modules.o

        CC      main.o

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgtk-win32-2.0
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgdk-win32-2.0
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:30: mine-sweeper.exe] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:205: binary] Error 2
```

Main Makefile:

```
################################################################################
# libs
LIBS_STATIC = -static

LIBS_MATH   = -l m
LIBS_CURSES = -l ncurses
LIBS_GTK    = `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`

ifeq ($(OS), linux)
  LIBS      = $(LIBS_MATH) $(LIBS_CURSES) $(LIBS_GTK)
else ifeq ($(OS), win)
  LIBS      = $(LIBS_STATIC) $(LIBS_MATH) $(LIBS_CURSES) $(LIBS_GTK)
endif

export  LIBS
```

Failing Makefile:

```
MAIN_OBJ_MODULES    = modules.o

MAIN_OBJS   = $(TMP_DIR)/main.o \
            $(patsubst %,$(MODULES_TMP_DIR)/%,$(MAIN_OBJ_MODULES))


$(BIN_NAME): $(MAIN_OBJS)
    $(Q)$(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS)
    @echo  "    CC  $@"
    @echo  ""
```

Why is it looking for something called 32?

What is missing?

**EDIT:**

Output of `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0` is:

```
 MINGW64 ~/mine-sweeper
$ pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0
-LC:/msys64/mingw64/lib -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

**EDIT:**

The installed package of GTK+-2.0 is:

```
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk2 2.24.32-2 [installed]
    GTK+ is a multi-platform toolkit (v2) (mingw-w64)
```

**EDIT:**

The requested libs seem to exist:

```
MINGW64 ~
$ find / |grep gtk-win32-2.0
/home/i5-5675C/mine-sweeper/bin/libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll
/mingw64/bin/libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll
/mingw64/lib/libgtk-win32-2.0.dll.a
find: failed to read file names from file system at or below ‘/’: No such file or directory

MINGW64 ~
$ find / |grep gdk-win32-2.0
/home/i5-5675C/mine-sweeper/bin/libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll
/mingw64/bin/libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll
/mingw64/lib/libgdk-win32-2.0.dll.a
/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/gdk-win32-2.0.pc
find: failed to read file names from file system at or below ‘/’: No such file or directory

MINGW64 ~
$
```

Comment: What's the output of `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`?

Comment: Added edit with the output of `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`

Comment: So it looks for `-lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0`, do you have those files?

Comment: Added edit with the output of find, which seems to indicate that those files are present.  Maybe the naming `*.dll.a` instead of `*.a` is giving this error?

Comment: *.dll.a means they are the dynamic libraries. But you've added `--static`, so it's looking for static libraries *.a.

Comment: So... is there anything I can do?

Comment: Either get static libs of gtk, or don't use --static.

Comment: Do you know where I can get the static libs?

Comment: I think you need to compile them yourself if you need static libs.